# How do you become eligible for Team Fortress 2 and Dota 2 booster packs?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I know that booster packs are given out to users who have got all possible card drops from a certain game, as stated in the [Steam Trading Card FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq). However, with Free-to-Play games such as Team Fortress 2 and Dota 2 you have to spend money on in-game items to get cards as there are no free card drops.

As a player who haven't paid enough to get a card from either game, I have no possible card drops. However, I'm not eligible for a booster pack either. What is required to get booster packs from F2P games? There does exist both TF2 and Dota 2 booster packs, as they are being sold at the Steam Market.

[image: Team Fortress 2 drop status]

Comment: I think you need to pay for at least 1 card drop. After that, you should be eligible for booster packs. This is just my theory, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @5pike That is my guess as well, but I'd like to know for sure :)

Comment: Dupe target just needs to be updated for F2P games, I believe.